# Oracle - execute Select query without INTO in plsql block at runtime

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to execute Select query in a procedure. 
 - the Select queries are unknown till run time, these will be passed as parameter

Main aim is to collect the stats from v$sql, v$sql_plan etc.

I have tried execute immediate and few other methods but failed. I can execute these queries by connecting sqlplus but I want to do this by a proc.

Requirement:

```
create or replace procedure p1 (p_sql IN clob)
as
begin
    --execute Select query which is passed in p_sql
    --capture v$sql 
end;
/
```

I cannot use INTO as I dont know the no. of columns/query.

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish, what sort or sql query is passed and what is the expected value returned by the procedure.
Also this is a very bad idea to submit a sql_qury to a stored procedure because your code is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: We are creating a tool to track some performance stats. The above stated problem is one the step. Once i run the proc, I want to capture v$sql etc.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] that demonstrates the problem and your attempt to solve it and where/why it fails.

Comment: You said you want to capture the `v$sql` data, in which case you already know the columns in `v$sql`. What is stopping you from using an `into`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DBMS_SQL` to parse the statement:

```
create or replace procedure p1 (p_sql IN clob)
as
  c integer;
begin
  c := dbms_sql.open_cursor;
  dbms_sql.parse (c, p_sql, dbms_sql.native);
  --capture v$sql 
end;
```

I believe that should be enough to generate the plan.

Comment: I have tried this but didnt get the expected value in rows_processed column, it is 0 instead of a <>0 value.
#########################################
execute p1('select /*identify2*/* from dual');
#########################################
select rows_processed,v.* from v$sql v where sql_text like '%s2%accounts%';
#########################################
yes it has generated the plan but the v$sql stats are not correct.
The same can be achieved by execute immediate.

Comment: again you need to explain more precisely what you want. what stats do you want, what the whole process is about and what is wrong with the result.

Comment: For eg - after running the proc ######execute p1('select /*identify2*/* from dual'); ######, I am expecting v$sql.rows_processed value as 1 becasue the query return 1 row and v$sql.elapsed_time should give me correct elapsed time. Dbms_sql.parse or Execute immediate are just parsing the Select query but not fetching the rows that's why v$sql is not giving proper stats. You try it, you will come to know. Also you can pass any other Select statement which returns more than 10000 rows, once you execute the statement using the above proc, you will get value as 0(instead of 10000) in rows_processed

Comment: So you intend to write a procedure that parses **any** SQL statement, executes it, and fetches **all** the rows?  What if the statement requires bind variables, do you want it to figure out the datatypes and bind appropriate dummy values too? I would really reconsider why you are doing this!

Comment: Why am doing this - I have some requirement. This is one of the problem which i am facing. I am already replacing bind variable with actual value before passing. Dbms_sql may solve my requirement, i will check it